# Setting up your linux box for GMT

Tags: linux, time, timezone

I would like to get my server time as close to GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) as possible.  What is best way to do this?

It's Ubuntu 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I can think of two things you might mean:

1. Set your timezone to GMT (UTC).  You can use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to pick the right timezone.
2. Keep your time as accurate as possible:  Install the "ntp" package.  I believe the defaults are good on Ubuntu 10, but you may want to edit /etc/ntp.conf and add a few lines like `server 0.us.pool.ntp.org` and `server 1.us.pool.ntp.org`; you'll want 4 or more of those.  You'll have to restart the ntp service for those changes to take affect.